# ListPopupWindow from my fragment giving Java.Lang.NullPointerException Error

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a view pager with fragments so I can swipe left and right to switch fragments. From inside of one of the fragments, I want to show a popup. I assume this needs to be a ListPopupWindow. What I have is a EditText field where they can enter in some data. I then check the entry and if there is one match, it is good. However, if there is more than one match, I want to show a popup window so they can select which one is the correct result. This is why I assumed it is ListPopupWindow and I do need to fill the list dynamically, just before the popup. I pondered if I should be just sliding up a new fragment with a list view on it instead of a popup. However, I am trying to do this at the moment with a ListPopupWindow but getting the Java.Lang.NullPointerException error. Here is the code I have so far, this code is in a method that can be called at any point.

```
            ListPopupWindow popup = new ListPopupWindow(context);  //context is passed in during onCreate of this fragment

        List<string> listForPopup = new List<string>(); //Create a new list to show on the popup for the user to select

        foreach (var c in validationResults) //Iterate through each of the possible results that the user must select
        {
            string name = lookupCourier(c.Item1); //The results only have an ID number, call lookup method to get the name from the ID.
            listForPopup.Add(name); //Add to the new list.
        }

        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, listForPopup); //Array adapter from the list.

        popup.SetAdapter(adapter); //Set the adapter to the popup list.
        popup.Width = 300; //Set the width of the popup.
        popup.Height = WindowManagerLayoutParams.WrapContent; //Have the popup window wrap the content. May have one or many to select from. Are there scroll bars?
        popup.Modal = true;
        popup.ItemClick += Popup_ItemClick; //Event handler to fire when the user selects the one item in the list.


        popup.Show(); //Show popup. NOTE: This is there I get the null excpetion.
```

And here is the stack trace from the exception(I think there are multiples):

```
 06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198): 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198): Unhandled Exception:
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198): Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11643 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:26 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at Android.Widget.ListPopupWindow.Show () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Widget.ListPopupWindow.cs:1527 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at PocketPacTracAndroid.Track.popupToSelectCourier (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 validationResults) [0x000a4] in C:\Projects\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\Track.cs:225 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at PocketPacTracAndroid.Track.validateBarcode (System.String rawBarcode) [0x0014e] in C:\Projects\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\Track.cs:192 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at PocketPacTracAndroid.Track.Barcode_KeyPress (System.Object sender, Android.Views.KeyEventArgs e) [0x0001c] in C:\Projects\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\Track.cs:88 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at Android.Views.View+IOnKeyListenerImplementor.OnKey (Android.Views.View v, Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e) [0x00018] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:2854 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at Android.Views.View+IOnKeyListenerInvoker.n_OnKey_Landroid_view_View_ILandroid_view_KeyEvent_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_v, Int32 native_keyCode, IntPtr native_e) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:2787 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:22b2513e-fc1d-45f2-938f-fbc85af3219a (intptr,intptr,intptr,int,intptr)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.widget.PopupWindow.getMaxAvailableHeight(PopupWindow.java:1219)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1090)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:524)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at mono.android.view.View_OnKeyListenerImplementor.n_onKey(Native Method)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at mono.android.view.View_OnKeyListenerImplementor.onKey(View_OnKeyListenerImplementor.java:30)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7081)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewPager.java:2567)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1369)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2356)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono    ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewRoot
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11643 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:26 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at Android.Widget.ListPopupWindow.Show () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Widget.ListPopupWindow.cs:1527 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at PocketPacTracAndroid.Track.popupToSelectCourier (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 validationResults) [0x000a4] in C:\Projects\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\Track.cs:225 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at PocketPacTracAndroid.Track.validateBarcode (System.String rawBarcode) [0x0014e] in C:\Projects\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\Track.cs:192 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at PocketPacTracAndroid.Track.Barcode_KeyPress (System.Object sender, Android.Views.KeyEventArgs e) [0x0001c] in C:\Projects\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\PocketPacTracAndroid\Track.cs:88 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at Android.Views.View+IOnKeyListenerImplementor.OnKey (Android.Views.View v, Keycode keyCode, Android.Views.KeyEvent e) [0x00018] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:2854 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at Android.Views.View+IOnKeyListenerInvoker.n_OnKey_Landroid_view_View_ILandroid_view_KeyEvent_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_v, Int32 native_keyCode, IntPtr native_e) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/52635947/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:2787 
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:22b2513e-fc1d-45f2-938f-fbc85af3219a (intptr,intptr,intptr,int,intptr)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.widget.PopupWindow.getMaxAvailableHeight(PopupWindow.java:1219)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1090)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:524)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at mono.android.view.View_OnKeyListenerImplementor.n_onKey(Native Method)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at mono.android.view.View_OnKeyListenerImplementor.onKey(View_OnKeyListenerImplementor.java:30)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7081)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewPager.java:2567)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1369)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2356)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
06-17 22:50:59.674 E/mono-rt ( 4198):   at andro
```

If anybody could please help me understand what this error is and how to fix it (ie get popup window working from my fragment) that would be appreciated. I am also open to other suggestions to achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set anchor to your `ListPopupWindow`. You can set any view as an anchor like this -

```
popup.setAnchorView(<your_view_here_to_which_you_want_it_to_be_anchored>);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this worked perfectly! Only difference is Xamarin exposes some things as properties. So, instead of

Comment: Sorry, hit the wrong button. So, instead of `popup.setAnchorView(view)` it was `popup.SetAnchorView = view;`. I then also had to globally define the view as `View view;` and then assign it in onCreateView like this `        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Track, container, false);`